# Azure SignalRTrigger not working with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-signalr

I have created an Azure SignalR Serverless service with Azure Functions.
My client is a .NET 6 WPF Application.

The negotiate function is working as expected, and the connection gets established succesfully.
The `CosmosDBTrigger`, `HttpTrigger` and `TimerTrigger` functions also work as expected.
However, the `SignalRTrigger` isn't working and I can't figure out why.

**SignalRTrigger function:**

```
[FunctionName("SignalRTest")]
public async Task SignalRTest([SignalRTrigger("myHub", "messages", "SignalRTest")] InvocationContext invocationContext, string message, ILogger logger)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Receive {message} from {invocationContext.ConnectionId}.");
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("signalRTestMessage", message);
}
```

**Client Configuration:**

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl("https://<SiteURL>.azurewebsites.net/api")
             .Build();
             
await connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith(async (e) =>
{
    try
    {
        await connection.InvokeAsync("SignalRTest", "TestMessage");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
});
```

The exception always returns the error message:

> Invocation failed, status code 404

I have configured the SignalR Upstream with the `signalr_extension` key generated in Azure Functions.

I have followed the official documentation on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) but still couldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I empathize with you since we've been struggling with sending messages as well even though so much documentation makes it appear trivial. One thought I had on your situation is: Should you use the URL from the negotiate response when creating a hubConnection?

Here's our typescript example that uses a NegotiateResponse object with the URL and AccessToken returned from the negotiate HTTP call:

```
this.signalRService.negotiate().subscribe({
  next: (negotiateResponse) => {
      let options = {
        accessTokenFactory: () => negotiateResponse.accessToken,
      };

  const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(negotiateResponse.url, options)
      .build();
```

P.S. As mentioned we are also struggling with message sending, so this may not be a solution for you although I hope it is.

Comment: I ended up using Isolated Functions instead of In Process, since the latter lose support in .NET 7. But my approach was still wrong, the GET petition is still required!